# Passing JSF 1.2 inputtext to a method in a session bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, mojarra, session-bean

I am learning JSF 1.2 and I have a scenario where a view "profile.jsf" is rendered using a request bean `BeanProfile`. The bean "BeanProfile" is a request bean because I need updated data in every request and refresh of the view. The view have a `<h:commandButton/>` that triggers a method in a session bean `LoginBean` and which should update the user profile before persisting it. So, I need to pass all the information in the profile view to the method in the session bean. I tried using the `<f:attribute/>` in the `<h:commandButton/>` like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" actionListener="#{beanLogin.updateUser}" value="Update">
    <f:attribute name="ttt" value="789"/> <!-- just for debug -->
    <f:attribute name="name" value="#{name}" /> <!-- I will pass just that one for the moment -->
</h:commandButton>
```

and the component:

```
<h:inputText id="name"
             binding="#{name}"
             value="#{beanProfile.name}"
             required="true" />
```

in my method i have:

```
public void updateUser(ActionEvent event) {
    /*Debug*/
    System.err.println("size: "+event.getComponent().getAttributes().size());
    System.err.println("--"+(String) event.getComponent().getAttributes()
            .get("ttt")+"--");;
    UIInput input = (UIInput) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("name");
    String text = (String) input.getSubmittedValue();
    System.err.println("++"+text+"++");
}
```

As a result I get:

```
2014-12-20T01:43:25.850+0100|Severe: size: 1
2014-12-20T01:43:25.850+0100|Severe: --789--
java.lang.NullPointerException ...
```

So I passed 2 parameters and I only got one in the method in the session bean and that's what caused the `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I don't know what i am doing wrong. I am working in Eclipse 4.4.1 SR1 using a dynamic web module 3.0 and GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1 which includes Mojarra 2.2.7.

**Update:**

I tried the same code using tomcat 8.0.15, MyFaces 1.2.12 and JSTL 1.2 which I was already using with GlassFish and Mojarra. I have the same problem and I found that the bean injection thought the `managed-property` in faces-config.xml does not work either (null value) in both configurations I used.

Comment: You mentioned in the beginning of the question that you are going with JSF 1.2. On the contrary, you mentioned at end of the question that you are using GlassFish 4.1 that already ships JSF 2.2.7 (which it indeed does) which is quite confusing and need a clarification about what version of JSF you are using. If you are learning JSF then, avoid using that legacy JSF 1.2 thing and start with an average later version - at least JSF 2. If you happened use a container that ships EL 2.2 or higher then, you could pass those parameters through  `action`/`actionlistener` directly to the backing bean

Comment: P.S. : Since you are already using GlassFish Server 4.1 which supports Servlet 3.1 - Java EE 7, you can pass those parameters to the backing bean directly using a parameterized `action` or `actionListener` method (even when using JSF 1.2).

Comment: I can not use JSF 2.0 or a more recent one because that's what they are asking me to use in a college assignment.